# RxJava2 Single take different route based on the item

Tags: rx-java2

I have the following code:

```
Single<Response<User>> single = service.registerUser();

single
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
     .map(Response::body)
     .flatMap(parentsRepsitory::writeUser)
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .flatMap(parentsRepsitory::getUser)
```

Where the *parentsRepository* is a repo wraping my realm database. The problems come when the server returns validation errors, however. So somewhere in my stream i want to have the equivalent of

```
if(response.code() == 201){
    // CONTINUE STREAM USING THE LOGIC THAT HANDLES SUCCESS
}elseif(response.code() == 400){
    // CONTINUE STREAM USING LOGIC TO HANDLE THE VALIDATION ERRORS
}
```

A solution I have previously implemented is as follows:

```
Observable<Response<User>> observable_from_api =
        service.attemptLogin(username, password)
               .share();

observable_from_api
        .filter(response -> response.code() == HttpStatus.HTTP_STATUS_200_OK)
        .//handle logic for success

observable_from_api
        .filter(response -> response.code() == HttpStatus.HTTP_STATUS_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        .//handle logic for validation errors
```

I don't like this solution for several different reasons. The main one being it just does not seem right. The second one being that the .share() method is only available on an *Observable* object. Since my network operation emits only one responce I would much rather use *Single* instead, but the .share() method is not available there.

Excuse me if this is a duplicate question, I have done some digging around and only found the solution I mentioned. I want to either see the optimal solution or be told explicitly that this is in fact the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define which kind of data you want your consumer to receive. I assume you want to receive in the consumer a `User` object.

These are the signatures of the method that you should create:

```
Single<User> handleSuccess(Response<User> response)

Single<User> handleError(Response<User> response)
```

And then you create you stream in this way:

```
service.registerUser()
    .flatMap(response -> {
         if (response.success) {
             return handleSuccess(response);
          } else {
             return handleError(response);
          }
     })
.subscribe(user -> logd("user: " + user.name));
```

Comment: You can also Single.error(yourException), to propagate an error down stream.

Comment: That's also an option, but then you have to move all your `handleError` logic in the subscriber